# How can I browse my Windows partition?

Tags: 11.10, windows, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to transfer files from Windows 7 to Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75178/how-to-transfer-files-from-windows-7-to-linux-ubuntu)

I'd like to get some files from my Windows partition, but I can't find it.

Do I need an application to do this, or is there a specific place I need to look?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu supports NTFS (Windows) file systems by default, and you don't need any special software to view them.

- If you installed Ubuntu side by side with Windows, then your Windows partition will show up in `Computer:///` in Nautilus.
- It will also show up in your file system under `/media/pathtopartition`.

Comment: i couldn't find it in system files..

Comment: @Rev3rse what directory did you look into?