# How to tell if Ubuntu is installed inside or alongside Windows?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on a computer with Windows on it (and later upgraded to 11.04 and  11.10). Now I can't remember whether Ubuntu was installed inside Windows (Wubi) or in its own partition. How can I find out which is the case?

Comment: Your question details are vague. How exactly did you install Ubuntu and Windows? For example, did you use `Wubi` or dual boot (separate partitions)?

Comment: I installed it along windows but when I upgraded it I am a bit confused.I have windows and ubuntu right now but Ubuntu is not found in add/remove list of windows.

Answer (score 3):

### From Ubuntu

Open your file browser and click "File System". Do you see a `host` folder which—on opening—contains folders like `Windows`, `Users`, and `Program Files`? If so, Ubuntu is installed within Windows.

### From Windows

Open "Add/Remove Programs" from the control panel. Is 'Ubuntu' listed among installed programs? If so, Ubuntu is installed within Windows.

Comment: I installed it along windows but I have upgraded it three times.I am not sure when the change was brought in.But I am still confused how Win could come inside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you should open your control panel inside windows and see if a software entry by the name of ubuntu is present or not. If not the ubuntu is installed outside windows and vice versa.

Comment: In the add remove list of windows Ubuntu is not listed.I initially installed it alongside windows but now what I find when I open is:                                                                Ubuntu                                                           Ubuntu(recoverymode)                                                            Previousversions                                                         Memorytest                                                          Memorytest                                                       M S Windows(on/dev/sda1)