# How do I access my music and documents from Windows7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, music, itunes

How do I access my Windows7 music library on Ubuntu 11.10?

I have just installed Ubuntu and I wish to copy my music library from iTunes to the banshee media player, I'll gladly give more details if necessary. I'm really new to Linux as a whole so if you can please use layman's terms.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu on the same computer, or on another one? Have you installed it alongside your old Windows installation or did you overwrite the old installation? Do you have your music and data on the same disk partition as your Windows installation, or on a separate partition?

Comment: Same computer, I selected the duel boot option during the install, I believe the music is on the same partition as windows 7, I never told it to do anything with it except download.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transfer files from Windows 7 to Linux Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75178/how-to-transfer-files-from-windows-7-to-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: To my understanding, no, I only seem to have two partitions, one labeled os, the other system.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the windows 7 partition in ubuntu, copy over the music, then unmount windows 7 partition.

Or you can keep windows 7 partition mounted on ubuntu (dangerous).  Then you can access your windows file from ubuntu all the time.  Just make sure you don't wakeup to the wrong OS after hibernate, or otherwise you face the danger of a corrupted partition.

Or if you don't mind redo the partition, you can create a shared data partition.  Put all your data, music, ... on the shared partition.  Both windows 7 and ubuntu can access it.  Just to make sure wake up to the correct OS when you hibernate.

Comment: Might I ask what you mean by wake up the correct os, also thank you.

Comment: also, I have created a new partition labeled Documents & Music, and when I try to copy over my music it says im not allowed, my other 2 partitions are: system and os, system has very few folders, one labled boot and the other system manager, the os partition has many folders, including one labled Ubuntu, the other windows, does this mean the partition is mounted on ubuntu?

Comment: waking up to the correct os means if you went to hibernate in windows, then you want to wake up into windows, same way, if you went to hibernate in Linux, you want to wake up in Linux.  Because went you went to hibernate, what ever the OS you were running still have the shared partition mounted, if you wake up to a different OS, it will mount it again, and that is BAD.

Answer (score 0):

This page takes you through how to do it.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions